# iOS: Facebook Login access token error: Falling back to loading access token from NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios-simulator

After configuring it based on the instructions I keep on getting this error and I am unable to successfully use Facebook Login on my app. I am running it on XCode 8.1 and using an iOS 10.1 simulator.

I followed the steps on the Facebook iOS SDK guide and put the Facebook login button in my view controller. I displayed the NSUserdefaults and one of the keys is "com.facebook.sdk:serverConfiguration" so I believe it is saving there.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        // User is logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
        NSLog(@"test");
    }
    else {
        FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
        loginButton.center = self.view.center;
        [self.view addSubview:loginButton];
    }
    _loginButton.readPermissions =
    @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit to show us your code and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: Added the code I implemented. I pretty much just followed the protocol listed on the facebook iOS SDK guide. I made the same build again but the problem is still arising.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is that the iOS Simulator is signed out after a restart of the app, this is caused by a bug in the Facebook SDK. It prevents the simulator from caching the access token.

You can fix this by adding the following line:

`key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_fix", key];`

in `FBSDKKeychainStore.m:94` and `FBSDKKeychainStore.m:135` 
just before:

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value forKey:key];`

Comment: The code lines you are referring too don't exist anymore. How about updating your answer ? Thanks

Comment: It still does in FBSDKCoreKit 4.18.0. See also https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/f7531a838a1ec3308721f335e801ac9f508feee4/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/TokenCaching/FBSDKKeychainStore.m

Comment: I actually can't find the line of code key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key]; am I missing something ?

Comment: You were right, I was referencing an incorrect line of code. Thanks.

Comment: The above fix will fix the problem that a simulator device doesn't stay logged in after a successful login and restart of the app. You need to provide more info to explain what exactly doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of these rather annoying log messages (*that's all they are*), go to FBSDKCoreKit's **FBSDKKeychainStore.m** file and comment lines 93 and 134:

```
//NSLog(@"Falling back to storing access token in NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug");
```

Voilá... gone!

**Note:** *This is current for Facebook SDK for iOS version 4.23.0.*

**For CocoaPods:**
The file can be found in your Xcode workspace under:
*Pods > Pods > FBSDKCoreKit > FBSDKKeychainStore.m*