# Thread 1: Breakpoint 2.4

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Hi I'm new in swift and I used a breakpoint because I had an error called Thread1 SIGABRT. But since I used the breakpoint, when I simulate I get a white window on the simulator and get this:

> objc[5893]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x1192bf998) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x1190e1880). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>   (lldb)

what's the meaning of this ? I don't understand. Thanks in advance

Here is the code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZSLs.png)

Comment: the error message doesn't say much to me. can you show the code you wrote that caused this error please?

Comment: @Mams D.Guirassy is it causing crash or just a warning?

Answer (score 0):

The *warning* in the console is not related to an exception error.

Instead of setting a breakpoint on a specific line set the global *Exception Breakpoint*

- Press <kbd>⌘7</kbd> to go to the Breakpoint Navigator
- Click on the <kbd>+</kbd> sign on bottom left and select Exception Breakpoint

  [image]
- Select only Objective-C breakpoints

  [image]
- Run your app

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did what you advised me but it's still the same

Comment: Did you remove the custom breakpoint (drag out of the editor)? With activated exception breakpoint the execution is supposed to stop at the line where the exception occurs. And you will get more information in the stack trace.

Comment: Yes and I got this : 2017-03-05 18:59:22.929 GoApéro[6644:129095] Falling back to storing access token in NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug
(lldb). I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Here are two related questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41047345/ios-facebook-login-access-token-error-falling-back-to-loading-access-token-fro. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033776/falling-back-to-loading-access-token-from-nsuserdefaults-because-of-simulator-bu found in a second using the search function